# FB.getLoginStatus not calling Facebook when user status is unknown

Tags: facebook, authentication

I try to call FB.getLoginStatus within a function, in the past I never had an issue, even when completely logged out and unconnected to Facebook.

Now, very recently, when the user status is unknown, the function does not even call Facebook to verify if I'm logged in.

Please help.

Comment: Can you post some code, or a link to a live example?

Comment: Just below body I have:

`<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 FB.init({appId: '<?php echo $applicationID; ?>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
</script>`

Comment: my function is the following:  

`function fbloginLocal() {  
         FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {  
           if (response.session) {  
            document.patapasregister.submit();  
           } else {  
            FB.login(function(response) {  
             if (response.session) {  
              document.patapasregister.submit();  
             } else {  
                       alert("not logged in again");  
             }  
            }, {perms:'email, user_about_me, publish_stream', clicktoshowdialog:"inviteFriends"});  
           }  
         });  
}`

Comment: This code is wrong. You need to initialise with oauth: true and then use response.authResponse in the getLoginStatus return. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/

Answer (score 1):

Found it, as the app was in sandbox mode, I was not able to login in without an already valid FB session. Tested while taking app out of Sandbox mode and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround:

```
if(FB.getAccessToken())
{
    FB.logout(function(response){
        document.location = logout_url;
    });
}
else
{
    document.location = logout_url;
}
```